# Azure App Configuration Feature Management

Tags: java, azure, maven, azure-java-sdk

I am looking for a solution using Maven and Java (Not Spring) where I can upload all my Key and labels and flag value by Json to deploy.
When I configure my project in Jenkins it should apply all the values which are changed.

Kindly provide me some directions, I tried lot with less material on this topic

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I managed to workout the solution. Basically following this [Microsoft Azure Link](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/java/api/overview/azure/data-appconfiguration-readme?view=azure-java-stable)
, but not completely solved my problem by this link though. Below is the Code Snippet which solved my problem. Code is not testable or productionable , this is just for reference.

```
public void process() {

    String value = "{\"id\": \"test\", \"description\": \"Sample Feature\",\"enabled\": false,\"conditions\": { \"client_filters\": []}}";
    DefaultAzureCredential  credential = new DefaultAzureCredentialBuilder().build();
    ConfigurationClient configurationClient = new ConfigurationClientBuilder()
            .connectionString(END_POINT)
            .buildClient();

    final ConfigurationSetting configurationSetting = new ConfigurationSetting();
    configurationSetting.setKey(format(".appconfig.abc/%s", "abc"));
    configurationSetting.setLabel("lable");
    configurationSetting.setContentType("application/vnd.microsoft.appconfig.ff+json;charset=utf-8");
    configurationSetting.setValue(value);

    configurationClient.addConfigurationSettingWithResponse(configurationSetting, NONE)
    }
```

Key points here is ".appconfig.abc" , At this point of time we don't have direct call to Feature Management , but we can add Key and labels to configuration as I said in the code snippet but with the Key as ".appconfig.abc" which you can get this info from portal. And the value should be a Json object, how we make this Json is upto you really.

Overall so much of information around the sites but none of them are connected in Java world for Azure. May be helpful to any one.

End Point , one can get from the Configuration Access Keys.